# Understanding torch.nn.Flatten

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I understand that Flatten removes all of the dimensions except for one. For example, I understand [flatten()](https://deeplizard.com/learn/video/fCVuiW9AFzY):

```
> t = torch.ones(4, 3)
> t
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1.]])

> flatten(t)
tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

However, I don't get `Flatten`, especially I don't get meaning of this snippet from [the doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html#torch.nn.Flatten):

```
>>> input = torch.randn(32, 1, 5, 5)
>>> m = nn.Sequential(
>>>     nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5, 1, 1),
>>>     nn.Flatten()
>>> )
>>> output = m(input)
>>> output.size()
torch.Size([32, 288])
```

I felt the output should have size `[160]`, because `32*5=160`.

**Q1.** So why it outputted size `[32,288]`?

**Q2.** I also don't get meaning of `shape` information given in the doc:

> [image]

**Q3.** And also meaning of parameters:

> [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a difference in the default behaviour. [`torch.flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html) flattens all dimensions by default, while [`torch.nn.Flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html#torch.nn.Flatten) flattens all dimensions starting from the second dimension (index 1) by default.

You can see this behaviour in the default values of the `start_dim` and `end_dim` arguments. The `start_dim` argument denotes the first dimension to be flattened (zero-indexed), and the `end_dim` argument denotes the last dimension to be flattened. So, when `start_dim=1`, which is the default for `torch.nn.Flatten`, the first dimension (index 0) is not flattened, but it is included when `start_dim=0`, which is the default for `torch.flatten`.

The reason behind this difference is probably because `torch.nn.Flatten` is intended to be used with `torch.nn.Sequential`, where typically a series of operations are performed on a batch of inputs, where each input is treated independently of the others. For example, if you have a batch of images and you call `torch.nn.Flatten`, the typical use case would be to flatten each image separately, and not flatten the whole batch.

If you do want to flatten all dimensions using `torch.nn.Flatten`, you can simply create the object as `torch.nn.Flatten(start_dim=0)`.

Finally, the shape information in the docs just covers how the shape of the tensor will be affected, illustrating that the first (index 0) dimension is left as it is. So, if you have an input tensor of shape `(N, *dims)`, where `*dims` is an arbitrary sequence of dimensions, the output tensor will have the shape `(N, product of *dims)`, since all dimensions except the batch dimension are flattened. For example, an input of shape `(3,10,10)` will have an output of shape `(3, 10 x 10) = (3, 100)`.

Comment: But then how `nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5, 1, 1)` gets converted to `[32,288]`?

Comment: @Rnj Those are the arguments corresponding to input channels, output channels, kernel size, etc. when creating a conv layer, not the shape of the input (see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html#torch.nn.Conv2d). The shape of the input after passing through the conv layer is `(32, 32, 3, 3)` , which flattens to `(32, 32 x 3 x 3) = (32, 288)`.